# Using if/else under a try method to login, however a successful login throws exception

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, try-except

Here is the snippet of the code I think is having a loop bug. I have been successful in having it retry upon failure or blank entry.
But once it logs in, it still keeps trying to login. Could someone take a look?

```py
print(f"The stripped captcha text is: {result}")
time.sleep(1)
if result:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'el-input')]//input[@name='captcha']").send_keys(result)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//button[contains(@type,'button')]").click()
        print("Captcha has been entered")
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//form[@class= 'el-form login-form el-form--label-left']//button[contains(@type,'button')]")
        if login_button:
            #try again by page refresh
            print("Captcha was entered but was wrong, trying again...")
            driver.refresh()
            login_attempt()
        else:
            print("The login attempt worked!")
    except:
        print("Seems to me that you are already logged in, but I will keep repeating this until you solve this loop")
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//form[@class= 'el-form login-form el-form--label-left']//button[contains(@type,'button')]")
        if login_button:
            #try again by page refresh
            print("Even after being logged in, trying again...this is not right.")
            driver.refresh()
            login_attempt()
        else:
            print("The login attempt may have worked!")
else:
    print("The captcha result was maybe blank.")
    time.sleep(2)
    if login_button:
        #try again by page refresh
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
        login_attempt()
    else:
        print("The login attempt worked!")
```

Sample Output:

```
Login button was found and variable has been recorded
Login attempt was called by your code
Username and Password were entered
The stripped captcha text is: vyiw4
Captcha has been entered
Captcha was entered but was wrong, trying again...
Login attempt was called by your code
Username and Password were entered
The stripped captcha text is: fhxax
Captcha has been entered
Seems to me that you are already logged in, but I will keep repeating this until you solve this loop
Seems to me that you are already logged in, but I will keep repeating this until you solve this loop
```

I tried to implement a re-attempt at failure logic, but failed to implement a successful scenario logic. I have no clue how to avoid the code to keep retrying, it is almost as if it skips the below else condition:

```py
else:
    print("The login attempt worked!")
```

Comment: What is the definition of `login_attempt`? Is it your "snippet"?

Comment: Did you mean this?
`def login_attempt():
                    login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//form[@class= 'el-form login-form el-form--label-left']//button[contains(@type,'button')]")
                    time.sleep(3)
                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'el-input')]//input[@type='text']").send_keys(username)
                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'el-input')]//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password)
`

Comment: the "if login_button" is throwing the exception because once the login is successful the element is not found. Wrap the "if login_button" in another Try/Except but make the Except what you have for your Else. You can confirm this by running it in debug and set a breakpoint on the "login =..." line and manually run that line- you will see it is returning a NoSuchElementException assuming this is selenium.

Comment: Thanks @mr_mooo_cow, I see that the exception is raised. Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='app']//form[@class= 'el-form login-form el-form--label-left']//button[contains(@type,'button')]"}
Yes this is selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a comment but figured I'd add a response to be more clear. I'm assuming this is selenium- if so you should tag it as such. The other assumption I am making is that the login button is not present after a successful login.

The main issue I see is that you are not handling the element not being present and assuming *login_button* will always be True/False, but in reality it will throw a NoSuchElementException. Also, it appears that your retry logic is too circular.

In your example:

- If captcha is found: try logging in
- If captcha is not found: try logging in
- If login appears to be successful: try logging in

In what scenario would it stop attempting to login?

Try something like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

print(f"The stripped captcha text is: {result}")
time.sleep(1)
if result:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'el-input')]//input[@name='captcha']").send_keys(result)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//button[contains(@type,'button')]").click()
    print("Captcha has been entered")
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//form[@class= 'el-form login-form el-form--label-left']//button[contains(@type,'button')]")
        if login_button:
            #try again by page refresh
            print("Captcha was entered but was wrong, trying again...")
            driver.refresh()
            login_attempt()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("The login attempt worked!")
else:
    #further check login status or assume user is already logged in
```

Also, instead of waiting a fixed 2s you could also utilize selenium's WebDriverWait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  #10s timeout
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "XPATH STRING")))
#continue code
```

Comment: Thanks, yes now I realize I haven't been clear. I should also mention that the captcha is always there. I need to enter it every time, however if my guess is blank or wrong, I need the code to retry. If successful, I need to stop trying to login. Let me work the recommendation from you in to mine and see.

Comment: Got an error for NoSuchElementException at 
try:
    login_button
This is when the logon was successful.

Comment: The assumption is if it hits that exception- login is no longer required since the button is absent. AKA when the login is successful we should be hitting that exception every time- at least with the code you have now. Unless I'm misunderstanding, if so feel free to start a chat.

Comment: I was using VSC to run and debug, I had all the breakpoints checkmarked and had forgotten about those. Your recommendation yielded successful result. (expected)
```The stripped captcha text is: 418FT
Captcha has been entered
Captcha was entered but was wrong, trying again...
Login attempt was called by your code
Username and Password were entered
The stripped captcha text is: ysnaw
Captcha has been entered
The login attempt worked!```

Comment: I would also like to add, that I appreciate your help with this. And I did not know about the WebDriverWait. I would be implementing it as you recommended, it does feel like a better way to wait for elements. Thank you! (this is my first python code)